# dynamic update data from csv (highchart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I really don't get it working.
the page loads but not the data.
I did try other things but i can't get it going

Trying to use a csv file with highstocks, but there seems to be an issue I am able to use csv files in highstocks using the csv fine, but it does not dynamically update the csv data, Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

here is what i have :

the csv is like this :

```
2018-02-25 16:26:48;21.7;33





$.ajax({
url: '/data/woonkamer/woonkamer2019.csv',
success: function (csv) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

     chart: {
type: 'spline',
animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
marginRight: 10,
events: {
    load: function () {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
     var series = this.series[1];
        setInterval(function () {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.random();
            series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

},

```
        data: {
            csv: csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')

        },

        title: {
            text: 'Daily Temperature And humidity'
        },


        subtitle: {
            text: 'Malosa'
        },

        xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",    
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
  second: '%H:%M:%S',
  minute: '%H:%M',
  hour: '%H:%M',
  day: '%e. %B',
  week: '%e. %b',
  month: '%b \'%y',
  year: '%Y'
    },
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000
```

},

```
        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: 'Temp + Humid',
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'temp',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                format: '',
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: "humid "
            },

            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                format: '{value:.,0f}'
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0
        },



        tooltip: {




        },

        plotOptions: {


            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',


                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (e) {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                    y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                                },
                                headingText: this.series.name,
                                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A-%e%b-%Y at %H:%M', this.x) + '<br/> ' +
                                     '</b><br/>'+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y + this.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix +'',
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },


        series: [{
    name: 'Temperature',
    data:[],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'c'
    }
},
{
    name: 'Humidity',
    data:[],

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' %'
                }
}]

    });
}
```

});

[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5rKG.png)

csv file local updated :

```
2018-03-01 09:25:34;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:35;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:36;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:37;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:38;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:39;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:40;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:41;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:42;22.1;29
2018-03-01 09:25:43;22.1;29
```

So i hope someone can help me with this so i can change it to all the charts:D

Comment: I suppose that your chart options JSON is not properly structured - there're two `data` properties in it.

Comment: Ok i did edit it, it starts now but does not get the new data, the lines go weird and stand still at the same place... any idea ?

Comment: Could you prepare a live demo (jsfiddle ideally) of this issue?

Comment: i can't do jsfiddle.. my file is generated on my pc every second .the problem is nothing happenswhen i load up my chart.. i just see the last data and thats it,, no update at all.. there must be something missing

Comment: here must be the problem under this line:      // set up the updating of the chart each second

Comment: Does the console throw any errors?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/23dgu74b/    this is my first time using charts.. this is the jsfiddle but not with the data i get every minute by csv... on my hd it gets from the csv what do i need to change ?

Comment: This demo shows how to add new data to the series initialized via CSV (hardcoded CSV and random values): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n6a1px4j/ In this example I used only ajax calls to get the data (CORS needs to be enabled): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kuw4nsk7/ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: maybe i put the wrong question, i just want to reload the chart without refreshing the webpage.

Comment: @KamilKulig i did try your code , it updates 1 line but the wrong way.. everything goes to the right and stay there updating.. the second line does not work

Comment: How do you expect the line to be updated? Please explain it on the example that I provided. By the way: second fiddle works too - you just need to enable CORS in your browser (as I mentioned).

Comment: @KamilKulig i explain. i have a homeautomation system that writes every second data to a csv file. i just want that the chart updates when it has new data without refreshing my browser

Comment: @KamilKulig  my data is like: see my update above.

Comment: Then why don't you launch `$.ajax()` function in 1 second intervals (as I did in the example that I posted before: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kuw4nsk7)? It doesn't refresh the browser. Then apply the data to the chart.

Comment: @KamilKulig thats the problem if i do that it doesnt work at all, see the screenshot above the csv entry...CORS is enabled.. your csv works not mine... i got 2 series aswell

Comment: This example may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rokf7u5s/ It uses the CSV that you provided.